# error de php Message: Unsupported operand types

Tags: php, mvc, operador

hola estoy realizando una operacion en php con parentesis; y me sale este error

codigo del error:

```
  Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in 
   C:\xampp\htdocs\olPrueba2\application\controllers\Admin.php on line 705
   A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: Error

    Message: Unsupported operand types

    Filename: controllers/Admin.php

    Line Number: 705

     Backtrace:
```

esta es la linea que dice tener error:

```
  $u=($yearC-$Yhire_date)*12;
```

como lo puedo resolver, las variables las tomo de la base de datos con un metodo, es de tipo fecha sera por eso?

codigo del metodo:

```
 public function getyearHire($roster_salesforcename){

  $this->db->select('roster_hire_date');
  $this->db->where('roster_salesforcename', $roster_salesforcename);
  $this->db->group_by('YEAR(roster_hire_date)');
  $data = $this->db->get('ol_roster');

  $response = $data->result();

   return $response;
  }
```

Comment: yo replique tu ejercicio y no me muestra error, añade que valores tienen las variables

Comment: Puedes añadir un poco mas de información, por ejemplo el contenido de las variables que estas utilizando para realizar tu operación.

Comment: ya edite la pregunta las variables son fecha y algunas las tomo con metodos y otras con  $monthC = $dateC->format('m');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si las variables son fechas no puedes utilizar el -.  Tienes que utilizar date_diff asi:

```
$u=date_diff($year,$Yhire_date);
```

Comment: yo ya los converti a entero,  para poder hacer la opracion, pero no me funciono sigue saliendo el mismo error, asi que ahora le puse la lina que me dijiste pero yo utilizo solo el año de la fecha entonces esta como string, porque lo tome asi: $yearC =  $dateC->format('Y'); y no funciona esa linea, sale este error:  Message: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given

Comment: Si los convertiste a string y quieres restarlos, entonces tienes que convertirlos primero a ints y luego restar usando -.